# 32 bit winform application doesn't run on 64 bit OS

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two laptops.

1) BuildLaptop-> The laptop that I have coded the application. Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit, Office 2007 for database

2)TestLaptop-> To test the application. Windows 7 ultimate 64 bit, Office 2007.

My application contains several dll files that built as AnyCPU and the application is also built as AnyCPU.

When I tried to test my application on TestLaptop it gave me an error:

> Microsoft.ACE.OleDb.12.0 provider is not registered on your machine.

So I uninstalled Office from TestLapTop and installed the Office as on BuildLapTop.

Again same error. Then I tried to compile all dlls and also my application to x64. The application could not start. Then I tried to compile only application to x64 and dlls to anyCPU. The error occured again.

So help me how to get my application run on the TestLapTop?

Comment: What are you using for your database, depending on your type you may have to define it in your ODBC on the 64 Bit Machine. Is it installed?

Comment: Is there a dependency on Office other than the OleDb provider?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to compile any project as `/platform:x86` if it uses any 32-bit unmanaged resources (DLL's, etc).

[image]

Comment: Will I have to compile the DLLs (also) to x86?

Comment: That worked. But I had to run the app as Administrator. Otherwise it doesn't open. What should I do for that? Second: I have read that 32 bit app can run on both (32 and 64) but 64 can run on 64. So your answer is the best way to run my app on every machine? Or I have to change coding (e.g. instead of converting to int like Convert.ToInt32(something), I should parse the 'something'?). Any suggestion. My Appreciation.

Comment: If you have to run it as an Admin you likely have some dependency which requires admin. And yes, you need to use `/platform:x86` (i.e. 32-bit) for any application which uses 32-bit unmanaged DLL's. No coding changes are needed because 32-bit on 64-bit is still 32-bit.

Comment: Last thing to ask.In my application I am using third party libraries like SourceGrid 4 that are built in "Any CPU". What should I do in this situation?

Comment: @DhavalR: if they make no usage of 32bit unmanaged DLL's, it will be Ok provided your executable is `/platform:x86`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure based on your comment you may be experiencing this issue.  If you have any Microsoft Office programs installed:

- Word
- Outlook
- Excel
- Powerpoint
- Etc

If they are the *32 Bit Revision* then you can't install a *64 Bit Access Database Engine* it will give you the following exception:

[image: Exception]

This will force you to install the *32 Bit Revision* onto your *64 Bit Machine*.  You may also require some additional configuration for the database in your *ODBC Data Source* through Administrative Tools.

[image: ODBC Data Source]

Hopefully that clarifies at least your error you mentioned in comment.  As for the compile, Sixlettervariables has a solution for that.

Hopefully that helps though.